# Horizontal CSS Menu with sub menu drop down is not aligning when scrolling

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, menu

I have a horizontal css menu where each menu option has a sub menu. This works as expected until the menu has an overflow set and the user scrolls. I believe this is because the sub menu is set to position:fixed. I can change it to position: absolute but then the submenu is behind the parent's scrollbar. Does anyone know how to fix this so it works as it does when scrolling is not needed?

Window maximized (no scrolling needed):
[image]

Window shrunk (scrolling needed):
[image]

Position absolute:
[image]

Sample markup of menu:

```css
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css');
html {
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% - 28px);
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 12px !important;
    color: #787878 !important;
}

.navbar-default {
    background-image: none !important;
    background-color: black !important;
    border: black;
}

    .navbar-default .navbar-brand {
        color: white !important;
    }

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active {
    color: #000;
    background: rgba(189, 189, 189, 1);
}

    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
        color: #000;
        background: rgba(189, 189, 189, 1);
    }

    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a {
        color: #555;
        background-color: rgba(189, 189, 189, 1) !important;
        background-image: none !important;
        box-shadow: none !important;
    }

#module-nav .navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding-left: 5px !important;
    padding-right: 5px !important;
    padding-top: 0px !important;
    padding-bottom: 0px !important;
}

#module-nav .navbar-nav > li {
    margin-right: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#module-nav .navbar-nav > li {
    padding: 10px !important;
    background-image: none !important;
}

/* NavBar Sub Menu http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/multi-level-navbar-menu */
.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

    .dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu {
        top: 0;
        left: 100%;
        margin-top: -6px;
        margin-left: -1px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
        -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px;
        border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
    }

    .dropdown-submenu:hover > .dropdown-menu {
        display: block;
    }

    .dropdown-submenu > a:after {
        display: block;
        content: " ";
        float: right;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-color: transparent;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
        border-left-color: #ccc;
        margin-top: 5px;
        margin-right: -10px;
    }

    .dropdown-submenu:hover > a:after {
        border-left-color: #fff;
    }

    .dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
        float: none;
    }

        .dropdown-submenu.pull-left > .dropdown-menu {
            left: -100%;
            margin-left: 10px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 0px;
            -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 0px;
            border-radius: 6px 0 6px 0px;
        }

#navbarCollapse {
    height: 40px !important;
}

.dropdown-menu > .active > a, .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus, .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover {
    background-color: #7ea700;
    background-image:none !important;
}

.dropdown-menu > .active > a, .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus, .dropdown-menu > a:hover {
    color: black !important;
}

.dropdown-menu > .active > a, .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus, .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover {
    color: black !important;
}


ul.multiselect-container > li {
    min-height: 1.8em !important;
}

#navigation {
    width: calc(100% - 195px);
    white-space: nowrap !important;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    
}

#navigation li{
    display: inline-block;
    float:none !important;
}

#icon-navbar{
    width: 195px;
    /*margin-top: 10px*/
}



.dropdown-menu{
    position: fixed;
    left: auto;
    top: auto;
}


    .dropdown-menu.multi-level ul {
        margin-left: 158px;
        margin-top: -28px;
        left: auto;
        top: auto;
    }

    .dropdown-menu.multi-level > li {
        display: block !important;
    }
    .dropdown-menu.multi-level ul>li {
        display: block !important;
    }
```

```html
<nav id="module-nav" role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" style="margin-bottom:5px; margin-top:50px; background-color:#e2e2e2 !important; border:none !important; min-height:10px !important; z-index:98">

  <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse" style="padding:0px;">
    <div style="overflow:hidden">
      <ul id="navigation" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left scrollbar-inner" style="position:absolute;">
        <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu Option 1<b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level" style="background-color:whitesmoke">
            <li><a href="/Menu 1" style="color:#777; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold;" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu Option 1</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu Option 2<b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level" style="background-color:whitesmoke">
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
              <a href='#' style="color:#777; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold;" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu Option 2</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="background-color:whitesmoke">
                <li><a href="/" style="color:#777; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; ">Sub Menu Option 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="/" style="color:#777; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; ">Sub Menu Option 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="/" style="color:#777; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; ">Sub Menu Option 3</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu Option 3<b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level" style="background-color:whitesmoke">
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
              <a href='#' style="color:#777; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold;" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu Option 3</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="background-color:whitesmoke">
                <li><a href="/" style="color:#777; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; ">Sub Menu Option 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="/" style="color:#777; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; ">Sub Menu Option 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="/" style="color:#777; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; ">Sub Menu Option 3</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu Option 4<b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level" style="background-color:whitesmoke">
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
              <a href='#' style="color:#777; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold;" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu Option 4</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="background-color:whitesmoke">
                <li><a href="/" style="color:#777; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; ">Sub Menu Option 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="/" style="color:#777; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; ">Sub Menu Option 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="/" style="color:#777; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; ">Sub Menu Option 3</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu Option 5<b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level" style="background-color:whitesmoke">
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
              <a href='#' style="color:#777; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold;" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu Option 5</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="background-color:whitesmoke">
                <li><a href="/" style="color:#777; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; ">Sub Menu Option 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="/" style="color:#777; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; ">Sub Menu Option 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="/" style="color:#777; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; ">Sub Menu Option 3</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu Option 6<b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level" style="background-color:whitesmoke">
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
              <a href='#' style="color:#777; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold;" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu Option 6</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="background-color:whitesmoke">
                <li><a href="/" style="color:#777; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; ">Sub Menu Option 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="/" style="color:#777; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; ">Sub Menu Option 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="/" style="color:#777; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; ">Sub Menu Option 3</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu Option 7<b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level" style="background-color:whitesmoke">
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
              <a href='#' style="color:#777; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold;" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu Option 7</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="background-color:whitesmoke">
                <li><a href="/" style="color:#777; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; ">Sub Menu Option 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="/" style="color:#777; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; ">Sub Menu Option 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="/" style="color:#777; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; ">Sub Menu Option 3</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu Option 8<b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level" style="background-color:whitesmoke">
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
              <a href='#' style="color:#777; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold;" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu Option 8</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="background-color:whitesmoke">
                <li><a href="/" style="color:#777; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; ">Sub Menu Option 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="/" style="color:#777; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; ">Sub Menu Option 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="/" style="color:#777; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; ">Sub Menu Option 3</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu Option 9<b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level" style="background-color:whitesmoke">
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
              <a href='#' style="color:#777; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold;" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu Option 9</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="background-color:whitesmoke">
                <li><a href="/" style="color:#777; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; ">Sub Menu Option 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="/" style="color:#777; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; ">Sub Menu Option 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="/" style="color:#777; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; ">Sub Menu Option 3</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu Option 10<b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level" style="background-color:whitesmoke">
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
              <a href='#' style="color:#777; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold;" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu Option 10</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="background-color:whitesmoke">
                <li><a href="/" style="color:#777; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; ">Sub Menu Option 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="/" style="color:#777; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; ">Sub Menu Option 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="/" style="color:#777; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; ">Sub Menu Option 3</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm afraid you can't achieve it with the native scrollbar. Maybe with a custom one (such as [IScroll](https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll))

Comment: @MoshFeu - thanks for the comment. I ended up implementing a custom scroll as suggested to overcome the issue.

Comment: Glad to hear :)